# Is it possible to show alert box on standard object

Tags: case, standard-objects, text, popup-window

Scenario is there is case object there is no any visual force page or trigger. i need to show alert box when user is edited the record of employeeId this is text field show alert message that "this employeeId doesn't exceed do you want to continue"

Answer (score 2):

This alert box functionality is not possible with Standard Salesforce page layouts.

It can be done with the use of visualforce.

Otherwise, use validation rule to restrict the user from editing.

Comment: yes message can see from validation rule. but i need in alert box

Answer (score 1):

There's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrqfAAC) or [two](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bra7AAC) for this (actually, more like 16 or so), and is currently under Product Management review. In the meantime, you can either use possibly a validation rule or trigger (which will block the save entirely until corrected), or you could write a Visualforce page or Lightning Component and override the default new/edit buttons. I'd recommend voting on the ideas so that we can have this as a standard feature without coding.

Comment: yes we can achieved from validation rule and override the page.. but scenrio is show message on alert box without usingn visualforce page,trigger,override etc.

Comment: @cloudZigZag You can't. That's the point. You've gotten *two* answers that said the same thing already, in two different ways. There's no feature that does this out of the box today, so you would need to write Visualforce.